# How to get syntax error of javascript code in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

working on a project in which user writes some javascript code, i just need the syntax error if exists in user's code but don't want to execute the code..Is there any library exists or solution exists in c#?

Comment: Have you done a google search? Have you tried anything out? Unfortunately this isn't a question for Stack Overflow

Comment: Can [this](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) help you?

Comment: tried alot but could'nt find the exact solution.

Comment: Thanks codroipa,but this is executing the script i just want to get syntax error of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint). It can parse and execute JavaScript. We are interested in parsing, so we can do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var validCode   = "alert('Hello World!');";
        var invalidCode = "alert['Hello World!');";
        var jsParser = new JavaScriptParser();
        var result = jsParser.Parse(validCode);
        result = jsParser.Parse(invalidCode); //Will throw...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Invalid input!!
    }
}
```